# Python turtle moving platform

Tags: python, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm working on Python game using turtles.

I have a player object that moves up and down (jump) on key press. I'm trying to add a moving platform that the player has to jump on.

I tried putting the moving platform in a `while` loop. The problem is since the `while` loop is running to keep the platform moving, the program does not detect key press.

I tried moving `turtle.listen()` inside the main `while` loop but that didn't work.

How do I keep the platform moving, in a `while True` loop, and have the listener active?

```
# moving platform
while True:
    s13.backward(3)
    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    if s13.xcor() < -200:
        s13.setheading(180)

...
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "Up")
```

Any advice is appreciated...

Comment: code did not retain formatting when i posted it...the turtle.listen( ) and onkey is outside the while loop

Answer (score 2):

A `while True:` statement has no place in an event driven environment like turtle.  There are at least a couple of solutions available to you.  The most straight forward is to use turtle's built-in `ontimer()` events to have a function independently run at a fixed (or variable) interval.

Another option is to introduce threading to the program.  However, since turtle is tkinter-based, you have to channel all the graphics operations through the main thread, which complicates things.

Try searching StackOverflow for:

- python turtle ontimer
- python turtle threading

A crude example:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

s13 = Turtle('square')
s13.color('red', 'blue')
s13.shapesize(1, 3, 2)
s13.penup()

def jump():
    s13.color(*reversed(s13.color()))

# moving platform
def move_platform():
    s13.backward(3)

    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    if s13.xcor() < -200:
        s13.setheading(180)

    screen.ontimer(move_platform, 100)

# ...
screen.onkey(jump, "Up")
screen.listen()

move_platform()

screen.mainloop()
```

The platform floats back and forth.  If you hit the up arrow (after clicking on the window to make it active) you'll see the platform swap its fill and outline colors as it floats.

Comment: Thanks...that's makes sense...the use of threads crossed my mind but i've never used them. I guess its time i learn how...

I removed while loop in main and added ontimer. it works but the s13 stops moving while the player is "jumping".

Comment: read some other posts, which also suggested ontimer() but there solution was a 100% either. are threads the only way to make two separate obj's move w/o interrupting one another? are they difficult to use?

Comment: @chappie, I can't say why your platform stops moving while the player is jumping as I've not seen the code.  Maybe `ontimer()` is still an option.

Comment: @chappie, you could edit your question to augment it or start a new question.  Depends on whether we're dealing with a new issue or another aspect of the current question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move:

```
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "Up")
```

to the top. Like this:

```
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(jump, "Up")

while True:
    s13.backward(3)
    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    if s13.xcor() < -200:
        s13.setheading(180)
```

...